# What is the maximum speedup vectorization can give?

Tags: parallel-processing, vectorization

I mostly develop in Python. There I noticed, that vecotrizing numpy operations gives a HUGE speedup; sometimes 1000x faster.

I've just heard in [Performance: SIMD, Vectorization and Performance Tuning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OJmxi4-twY) by James Reinders (former Intel Director), that vectorization gives at most a speedup of 16x (minute 03:00 - 03:09), but parallelization can give up to 256x speedup.

Where do those numbers come from? I thought the speedup for parallelization is the number of threads, hence 8x on my [Intel i7-6700HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88967/intel-core-i7-6700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html)?

### Python vectorization example

This is one example where I see a huge difference:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def print_durations(durations):
    print('min: {min:5.1f}ms, mean: {mean:5.1f}ms, max: {max:6.1f}ms (total: {len})'
          .format(min=min(durations) * 10**3,
                  mean=np.mean(durations) * 10**3,
                  max=max(durations) * 10**3,
                  len=len(durations)
                  ))

def test_speed(nb_items=1000):
    print('## nb_items={}'.format(nb_items))
    durations = timeit.repeat('cosine_similarity(mat)',
                  setup='from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity;import numpy as np;mat = np.random.random(({}, 50))'.format(nb_items),
                  repeat=10, number=1)
    print_durations(durations)

    durations = timeit.repeat('for i, j in combinations(range({}), 2): cosine_similarity([mat[i], mat[j]])'.format(nb_items),
                  setup='from itertools import combinations;from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity;import numpy as np;mat = np.random.random(({}, 50))'.format(nb_items),
                  repeat=10, number=1)
    print_durations(durations)

print('First vectorized, second with loops')
test_speed(nb_items=100)
test_speed(nb_items=200)
test_speed(nb_items=300)
test_speed(nb_items=400)
test_speed(nb_items=500)
```

Comment: I just realized that caching/good memory access patterns might be the reason for the huge speedup I see in my Python example

Comment: So [locality of reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) might be much better with the vectorized version